# Вывод ajax результата в родительский span

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

у меня имеется вот такой вид html:

```
<li class="file" id="ид для передачи в пхп"><a href="ссылка не играет роли">текст</a> <span id="size">Сюда передать результат</span></li>,
```

Я написал php обработчик, возвращающий результат и js-скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.file').mouseenter(function(){
    $.post("/путь/до/обработчика.php", {f_size:$(this).attr('id')}, function(data) {
        $('#size').text(data); // Как добавить в span? $(this)?
        console.log(data); 
    });
    return false;
});  });
```

Но я не знаю, как передать результат в span объекта, на который я навёл мышь. `<li>` тегов в документе очень много, а результат возвращается только в первый, как можно вернуть результат в `span`, родителем которого является `<li>`, на который наведена мышь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.file').mouseenter(function(){
        let that = $(this);
        $.post("/file.php", {f_size:that.attr('data-id')}, function(data) {
            $(that).find('span').html(data);
            console.log(data);
        });
        return false;
  });
});
```

И не используйте одинаковые id. На страницу может быть только 1 уникальный id. Измените на data-id, если там передаётся только информация для PHP.

Comment: Последовал вашему совету - то что мне нужно, отличный вариант! Спасибо! Про data-id отдельная благодарность, буду иметь ввиду.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите, создал прототип и описал действия, которые могут вызвать вопросы:

```js
$(".file").each(function() { // проходим по всем .file
  const id = $(this).attr('id'); // запоминаем id текущего .file

  $(this).hover(function() { // вешаем событие hover на каждый .file
    setTimeout(() => { // имитируем загрузку данных (спустя секунду)
      const data = { // создаём фейковые данные
        'id1': {
          text: "some text 1"
        },
        'id2': {
          text: "some text 2"
        }
      }

      $(`#${id} .size`).text(data[id].text); // подставляем в id текущего .file в его дочерний компонент .size текст из фейковых данных по ключу, который равен id
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="file" id="id1">
    <a href="#">текст</a> <span class="size">Сюда передать результат</span>
  </li>
  <li class="file" id="id2">
    <a href="#">текст</a> <span class="size">Сюда передать результат</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Я не знаю как у Вас выдаёт результат на запрос Ваш обработчик (`/путь/до/обработчика.php`). Если у Вас выдаётся отдельно для каждого id своя data - тогда достаточно будет сделать `.text(data.text);`. Но лучше загрузить все данные единовременно при инициализации (если их не много) и подставлять по ключу уже на ховере, как в примере.

Comment: Хороший вариант, тяжеловат для меня, как начинающего, но тем не менее, работает! Описанный ниже вариант оказался более упрощённым и понятным мне, всё же спасибо, ваш вариант так же пригодится в будущем.